# Symfony2 No route found for "GET /": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, url-routing

I have two routes defined in in a bundle inside `routing.yml` and that are:

```
dm_dashboard:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: DigitalManagerERPBundle:Default:login }
    methods:  [GET]
dm_dashboard:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: DigitalManagerERPBundle:Default:processLogin }
    methods:  [POST]
```

i.e. chose the first route for `GET` method and chose the second for the `POST` method. But when I try to get that to path, I am getting this error

> No route found for "GET /": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

and none of the routes get executed. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Why none of the routes executes?

P.S `Newbie here`

Comment: Try to use different names for the 2 routes (`dm_dashboard_get` and `dm_dashboard_post`?).

Comment: Maybe you should add a route without `methods:`. I don't know if the method is recognized as `GET` if no form is sent.

Comment: The `router:debug` and `router:match` console commands are helpful for  debugging routing issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have both the same name

Try this:

```
dm_dashboard_login:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: DigitalManagerERPBundle:Default:login }
    methods:  [GET]
dm_dashboard_process:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: DigitalManagerERPBundle:Default:processLogin }
    methods:  [POST]
```